# Derivative of (1-t/m)^m

Tags: calculus, derivatives

We know that...

[image: formula8]
.

However, I am trying to derive with respect to *n*...

[image: formula9]
.

But I am unsure how to do so as *n* is the exponent outside of the brackets as well as inside the brackets.

The farthest I can get is...

[image: form11]
But then I get lost. I tried to use *ln* on both sides but I always end up with the wrong answer. Can someone please show a step-by-step process to derive this with respect to variable *n*?

Comment: I assume that you meant $n$ instead of $m$ in your title and the first image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a case where logarithmic differentiation makes life easier
$$y=\left(1-\frac{t}{m}\right)^m\implies \log(y)=m\log\left(1-\frac{t}{m}\right)$$ Differentiation with respect to $m$
$$\frac{y'}y=\log\left(1-\frac{t}{m}\right)+m\frac{t}{m^2 \left(1-\frac{t}{m}\right)}=\log\left(1-\frac{t}{m}\right)+\frac{t}{m-t}$$
Now
$$y'=y \times \frac{y'}y$$

Answer (score 2):

You may have a few typos in your text:

1) Eq. (1): limit when "n" goes to $\infty$;

2) Eq. (2): the derivative symbol is misplaced.

Assuming you want to differentiate $(1-t/n)^n$ with respect to $n$, the way to do it is to use the exponential, $\it{i.e.}$, your expression reads:

$\exp[n \ln(1-t/n)]$,

which you can easily differentiate now.

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{aligned}\dfrac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dn}\left(1-\dfrac{t}{n}\right)^n&=\dfrac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dn}\exp n \ln\left(1-\dfrac{t}{n}\right)\\&=\underbrace{\dfrac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d\left(n\ln\left(1-t/n\right)\right)}\left[\exp n \ln\left(1-\dfrac{t}{n}\right)\right]\cdot\overbrace{\dfrac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dn}\left[n\left(1-\dfrac{t}{n}\right)\right]}^{\text{Use Product Rule}}}_{\text{By the Chain Rule}}\end{aligned}$$

---

**Aliter**:

Use the Generalized Power Rule: $\left[u(x)^{v(x)}\right]'=u(x)^{v(x)}\cdot\left[\ln u(x)\cdot v(x)\right]'$.

$$\begin{aligned}\dfrac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dn}\left(1-\dfrac{t}{n}\right)^n&=\left(1-\dfrac{t}{n}\right)^n\end{aligned}\cdot\dfrac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dn}\left[n\ln\left(1-\dfrac{t}{n}\right)\right]$$

Can your Proceed?